# Breakpoint not called

Tags: java, hibernate, debugging, intellij-idea

I have this method:

```
public boolean checkActivationAndSolve(String email, String code) {
    try {
        System.err.println("CHECK ACTIVATION METHOD CALLED");

        User targetUser = userService.findByName(email);
        int targetID = targetUser.getUserId();
        UserActivation activation = userActivationService.findByTargetId(targetID); // <-- Breakpoint
        if (activation != null) { // <-- Breakpoint
            if (code.equals(activation.getActivationToken())) { // <-- Breakpoint
                userActivationService.delete(activation);
                targetUser.setEnabled(true);
                userService.update(targetUser);

                this.createIntranet(targetID);

                return true;
            }
            else {
                System.err.println("Activation Code invalid");
            }
        }
        else {
            System.err.println("Activation == null");
        }
        return false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Some Exception occurred: \n" + ex.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

The breakpoint positions are mentioned by comments in the lines. Furthermore, I have some breakpoints in the called method `findByTargetId()` to solve the problem why I always get an error message when trying to activate my account.

The problem I am facing is that the debugger stops at the first of the breakpoints above, then the method should be called but none of the breakpoints in this method are used. I never get any stops inside this method. It seems like it isn't even called because when I execute this query manually, it returns exactly the data I am expecting and this data would make the above method return `true` which isn't the case.

**Is it possible that this method is not called?** If not, is there another problem with my code? I am stuck with this issue for about 4 hours now and I want to proceed in developing the next features.

**EDIT:** I tried setting a breakpoint on the head of the method `findByTargetId()` and IntelliJ marks this breakpoint with error: "Method not found in class [....]". Why does that happen? The method definitely exists in the specific class and also the interfaces.

**EDIT 2:** The code is out of sync indeed. IntelliJ recompiles the code when hitting the "Execute" button, but apparently the new package isn't deployed or it's not compiled correctly. I can't figure out why that happens but maybe one of you guys got an idea. If so, please let me know because this bug throws me back days in my plans.

Any help is greatly appreciated. If you need more code, just tell me what and I'll add it.

Comment: I hope your code and deployed one are in sync

Comment: Of course they are. I just made sure that it is by redeploying and even restarting the server (I am using Glassfish Community)

Comment: so the `activation` is null? Your code is out of sync. As for the question - NO, it is not possible that second `if` statement is passed by just like that

Comment: I stopped the Glassfish and did "Save All" in my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate) and restarted the IDE. Then I hit the debug button again and waited for the server to start up completely. Still no success. I can't figure out why the code might be out of sync.

Comment: I discovered something very interesting: as you both already assumed, the code is not in sync indeed. The problem is that i don't know why. I restarted even the whole computer and did "Save All" and "Sync" in my IDE and still no change.

Comment: Could you try a breakpoint inside the catch? The System.err showing up is no certain thing.

Comment: Yeah I could add this breakpoint but it wouldn't help because IntelliJ doesnt deploy the new code. I imported it in Eclipse and there my code works fine... Strange.